# React - component doesn't re-render after delete request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have problem that after deleting element from my list, component doesn't want to re-render. When I go through routing to some subpage and then back, item is already removed, same if I sort list, then it also disappears. The thing is that I don't want to force user to refresh the website or sort to see the effect. It used to work if I pass to

> deviceList props as a "props.data" instead of "devices"

(will bold the place in the code). Does anyone has idea how to fix it? I'm still kinda new to react hooks and perhaps I just gotta adjust useEffect a bit better,
props.selectedDevices is taken from redux and just gets the ID of deleted item, my code:

Parent:

```
function App(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("")
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => getDeviceDataTotal(), [])

  const getDeviceDataTotal = () => {
    console.log('refresh clicked')
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/device")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setData(res))
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  };

  const deleteDevices = (e) => {
    console.log('delete clicked')
    props.selectedDevices.map(el => {
      return fetch(`http://localhost:4000/device/delete/${el}`, {
        method: "DELETE"
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(() => getDeviceDataTotal())
        .catch(err => {
          throw err;
        });
    });
  }

  const filterList = e => {
    let filteredList;
    filteredList = data.filter(el => {
      return el.device_id.includes(searched);
    });
    setFilter(filteredList)
  };


  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme(theme("#96BF1B", "#ffffff"))}>

        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => <Dashboard classes={classes} dataDevice={data} refresh={getDeviceDataTotal} filtered={filter} filterList={filterList} deleteDevices={deleteDevices}/> }
          />
          ......
        </Switch>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Child Component:

```
function Dashboard(props) {
  const [selectedSort, setSelectedSort] = useState("1")
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState(props.dataDevice)


  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true
    const fetchData = async() => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/device")
        const response = await res.json()
        if (isSubscribed) {
          setDevices(response)
         }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }

    fetchData()
    return () => isSubscribed = false
  },[])

  useEffect(() => props.refresh() ,[devices])


  useEffect(() => sortDeviceData(), [selectedSort])

  const sortDeviceData = () => {
    switch(selectedSort) {
      case "device":
        (filtered.length ? filtered : dataDevice).sort(function(a,b) {
          return (a.device_id.toUpperCase() < b.device_id.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.device_id.toUpperCase() > b.device_id.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0
        })
        setDevices(dataDevice)
        break;
      case "customer":
        (filtered.length ? filtered : dataDevice).sort(function(a,b) {
          return (a.customer.toUpperCase() < b.customer.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.customer.toUpperCase() > b.customer.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0
        })
        setDevices(dataDevice)
        break;
      case "server":
        (filtered.length ? filtered : dataDevice).sort(function(a,b) {
          return (a.server.toUpperCase() < b.server.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.server.toUpperCase() > b.server.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0
        })
        setDevices(dataDevice)
        break;
      case "creation":
        (filtered.length ? filtered : dataDevice).sort(function(a,b) {
          return (a.createdAt.toUpperCase() < b.createdAt.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.createdAt.toUpperCase() > b.createdAt.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0
        })
        setDevices(dataDevice)
        break;
      case "update":
        (filtered.length ? filtered : dataDevice).sort(function(a,b) {
          return (a.updatedAt.toUpperCase() < b.updatedAt.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.updatedAt.toUpperCase() > b.updatedAt.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0
        })
        setDevices(dataDevice)
        break;    
      default: 
        return setDevices(dataDevice)
    }
  }


  const { classes, logged, dataDevice, filtered } = props;
  return logged ? (
    <main style={{ display: "flex" }} key={dataDevice}>
      <section className={classes.sectionLeftContainer}>

        <div className={classNames(classes.search, classes.tableBackground)}>
          <InputBase
            placeholder="Search…"
            classes={{
              root: classes.inputRoot,
              input: classes.inputInput
            }}
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Search" }}
            onChange={e => props.getSearched(e.target.value)}
          />
          <Button
            variant="outlined"
            className={classes.searchBtn}
            onClick={e => props.filterList(e)}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="outlined"
            className={classes.btnAddDevice}
            onClick={e => {
              if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this device")) {
                props.deleteDevices(e);
              }
            }}
          >
            <DeleteIcon />
            Delete devices
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <FormControl className={classes.selectContainer}>

            <Select 
              value={selectedSort} 
              style={{position: 'absolute', right: 0, bottom: 10, width: 150}}
              onChange={e => setSelectedSort(e.target.value)}
              >
              <MenuItem value="1">Default</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="device">Device</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="customer">User</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="server">Server</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="creation">Creation date</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="update">Update date</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div>
          <DeviceList
            classes={classes}
            **deviceData={devices} if props.data - works well but sorting doesn't work**
            filtered={filtered}
          />
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to force a React component render but they are essentially the same.  The first is using `this.forceUpdate()`, which skips `shouldComponentUpdate`:

```
someMethod() {
    // Force a render without state change...
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Assuming your component has a state, you could also call the following:

```
someMethod() {
    // Force a render with a simulated state change
    this.setState({ state: this.state });
}
```

There's likely a better, more "React-y" way to render a component properly, but if you are desperate to get a component render on command, this will do.

Comment: setState is the proper method to call an update to the component in a case like this.

Comment: `this.forceUpdate()` must be avoided at all cost, `setState` is the proper way to update a component.

Comment: as I use hooks so I tried to use setDevices(devices), after clicking delete but unfortunately it doesn't change anything and eventho element is removed from database, it is still visible

Comment: use `setState` to re-render the componenet OR if you want the whole page to reload, you can use `window.location.reload();`. I hope it gets you what you need.

Comment: hmm thanks for suggestions:) but setState in hooks would look like setDevices(devices) in my case, it doesn't work, component still doesn't re-render. Window.location.reload() works and for now I keep it as a dirt hack to let user see element be deleted however I still gotta find out how to re render only component because this refresh of whole page doesn't look well

Comment: Try using `this.source.refresh();`. I am using this in my angular project and it works perfectly. Only the component re-renders.

Comment: unfortunatelly with functional component there is no "this" and source.refresh() doesn't work here...

Answer (score 0):

You should pull this delete function up to the parent component that holds the list of devices. Then pass the function down as props and call it from the child component with the device you want to delete.

```
const deleteDevices = (e) => {
  return fetch(`http://localhost:4000/device/delete/${e}`, {
    method: "DELETE"
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(_ => setDevice(devices.filter(device => device !== e)))
  .catch(err => {
    throw err;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Separate Fetching Logic into a function and call it after your delete request so data is updated.

```
const getData = () => {
  // fetch data
}

useEffect(() => {
  getData()
}, [])

const deleteData = () => {
  fetch(...).then(() => {
    getData()
  })
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your parent component useEffect hook.

```
//...

const getDeviceDataTotal = () => { 
    // Api call...
};

// Reference the getDeviceDataTotal function inside the hook.
useEffect(getDeviceDataTotal, []);

//...
```

Alternatively wrap your api call function in a useCallback hook and include it as a dependency in your useEffect hook.

```
//...

const getDeviceDataTotal = useCallback(() => { 
    // Api call...
},[]);

// Include getDeviceDataTotal as a dependency.
useEffect(() => getDeviceDataTotal(), [getDeviceDataTotal]);

//...
```